# Query cosmosDB: get last element in array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

i have document like this:

```
    { "id": ....,
    "Title": ""title,
    "ZipCodes": [
            {
                "Code": "code01",
                "Name": "Name01"
            },
            {
                "Code": "code02",
                "Name": "Name02"
            },
            {
                "Code": "code03",
                "Name": "Name03"
            } ],
"_rid": .......,
"_self": .......,
"_etag": ......,
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": ......
```

i was used to command

```
select c.id, c.ZipCodes[ARRAY_LENGTH (c.ZipCodes) -1] as ZipCodes from c
```

But i got error, how can i query last element ZipCodes in cosmos DB.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ARRAY_SLICE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-slice) for this. When passed `-1` it returns an array containing the last element of the original array. Then index into that with `[0]` to get the single element contained (i.e. the zip code itself.)

```
SELECT c.id, 
       ARRAY_SLICE(c.ZipCodes,-1)[0] AS LastZipCode
FROM c
```

Comment: Any idea If Name in that array is Date and how do we get the latest record without using a UDF.

Comment: @jubi - you should ask a new question about this along with a sample document and desired results

Comment: Max limit reached for the questions

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using select you can query the subdocument , i think you should use the where condition as follows,

```
SELECT value udf.sortZipCode(c.ZipCodes)
from c where c.id=2 and c.Title='title'
```

However, here is a user defined function (UDF) that will do the trick:

```
function sortZipCode(ZipCode) { 
  function compareTimeStamps(a, b) {
    return a.TimeStamp - b.TimeStamp; //implement your logic
  }
  return scanLog.sort(compareTimeStamps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i got error, how can i query last element ZipCodes in cosmos DB.

I agree with Sajeetharan mentioned that we could use the UDF to do that. And we could do that with UDF easily.

**UDF code**

```
function userDefinedFunction(zipcodes){

    return zipcodes[zipcodes.length-1];
}
```

[image]

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT c.id,c.Title,udf.GetLastRecord(c.ZipCodes) as ZipCodes FROM c
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your support. 
Do you know how to count distinct "Code" on "ZipCode" ?

Comment: Hi Tom, Could you help me how to count by value in cosmos DB ?